Caused by: org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.MalformedQueryException: Encountered " "delete" "DELETE "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting one of: "base"
I can not write/delete data on rdf4j-server running on tomcat via rdf4j-workbench.
It seems to be set as read-only. How can I open the server up for read/write via configuration?
Query:
delete {<http://www.tv.com/products/deli/guid-0196ca5b-0606-48bf-9cb1-e9420c870c8a> <http://metallica.com/organisation/Ceo> <http://metallica.com/organisation/myman666>} where {<http://www.tv.com/products/deli/guid-0196ca5b-0606-48bf-9cb1-e9420c870c8a> <http://metallica.com/organisation/Ceo> <http://metallica.com/organisation/myman666>}

I have tried introducing users as described as described here:


Write access
/repositories/*
GET
POST
PUT
DELETE


editor




Read only access to repository data

viewer

    <security-role>
            <description>
                    Read/write access to repository data
            </description>
            <role-name>editor</role-name>
    </security-role>

Logging in with a user having the editor role and I still get the same response.
My query is valid and has been running fine until we moved to new servers with the same version.
Workbench 2.2.
Tomcat:
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.76
Server built:   Mar 9 2017 13:49:01 UTC
Server number:  7.0.76.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.18.0-553.16.1.el8_10.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_422-b05
JVM Vendor:     Red Hat, Inc.
